# CDI @Inject Instance @Any - But instance never populated with instances

Tags: java, jboss7.x, cdi

Why does 'instance' never iterate over any implementations? What am I missing?

JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-19)

```
public interface Simple { }
public class SimpleA implements Simple { public SimpleA() { } }
public class SimpleB implements Simple { public SimpleB() { } }
public class SimpleUser {
    @Inject @Any Instance<Simple> instance;

    @PostConstruct public void init() {
        for (final Simple simple : instance) {
            System.out.println(simple);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `beans.xml` within your `META-INF` or `WEB-INF` directories of the jar/war, that provides the beans? JBoss 7.x/EAP 6.x uses CDI 1.0, so all beans are picked up for CDI.

Comment: Thanks, I do have one, but it's empty. I don't think it is necessary to get it working though. Other injections are working, like @ EJB without adding them in beans.xml. I've now got one implementation being printed, but not two. Adding "@ Default" and "@ Alternative" doesn't change things. I think I'm missing something fundamental. If there's one implementation @Inject works also by the way...

Comment: I tried your code in a sample war and it worked. The code above is OK.

Comment: OK, thanks, really strange. I finally got it working. Maybe the fact that I use DeltaSpike and have several EJB's and web services with RestEasy is interfering with this, but after creating producer methods for each implementation I could iterate over the implementations. For me it kind'a defeats the point because you have to provide a method per implementation...

    @Produces
    public SimpleA getSimpleA(@New final SimpleA simpleA) { return simpleA; }

Comment: Usually, all mentioned components play nicely together. DeltaSpike has a `@Veto` annotation to disable certain beans. CDI beans can be disabled within CDI's portable extensions. Depending on your class path, there might be something, that vetoes your beans, but it's rather unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone else, I also am using Deltaspike 1.5.2 and am running into the same issue (if I remove Deltaspike, I no longer have the problem).

In my case adding producer methods did not solve it. After looking around I BeanProvider which gets around the problem but is far from elegant.

https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/core.html#BeanProvider

I had to call

`List<MyServiceInterface> myServiceList = BeanProvider.getContextualReferences(MyServiceInterface.class, false, false);`

There are probably better ways. I notice Deltaspike turns on a bunch of extensions by default, but couldn't find docs on how to disable the ones I am not using as I suspect one may be causing this issue.

Comment: DeltaSpike doesn't change the behavior in that area. That isn't even possible (without a veto on the bean/s).
Some CDI-Containers just have bugs in case of Inject+Any+Instance, but that isn't related to DeltaSpike.